# blank Attribute with value in XML with XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have below XMl and I need to replace root="" with Dynamic GUID value. this can be anywhere in XML document. it does not work with below XSLT. This is just the extended text to post successfully.

```
            <ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
            <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" extension="2015-08-01"/>
            <id root=""/>
            <code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LN"
            displayName="Summarization of Episode Note"/>
            <title>Patient Summary Document</title>
            <languageCode code="en-US"/>
            <component>
            <structuredBody>
              <component>
                <section>
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.6.1"/>   
                  <entry typeCode="DRIV">
                    <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.30"/>
                      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.30" extension="2015-08-01"/>
                      <id nullFlavor="UNK"/>  
                      <informant>
                        <assignedEntity>
                          <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.86.3.1" extension="STHS"/>
                          <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                          <telecom nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                          <assignedPerson>
                            <name nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                          </assignedPerson>
                          <representedOrganization>
                            <id root="" extension="STHS" displayable="true"/>
                            <name>STHS</name>
                            <telecom nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                            <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
                          </representedOrganization>
                        </assignedEntity>
                      </informant>
                    </act>
                  </entry>
                </section>
              </component>
            </structuredBody>
            </component>
            </ClinicalDocument>
```

I have below XSLT. but it does not work for above highlighted tag.

```
            <xsl:variable name="GUID" select="'FF1122'"/>

            <xsl:template match="id/@root[.='']">
                <xsl:attribute name="root">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$GUID"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>


        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The tag isn't highlighted.  Could you edit to put a comment node on the tag you're talking about?

Comment: <id root="" extension="STHS" displayable="true"/> for this one it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:isc="http://extension-functions.intersystems.com"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"            
    xmlns:ns1="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="GUID" select="'FF1122'"/>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:id/@root[.='']">
    <xsl:attribute name="root">
      <xsl:value-of select="$GUID"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Since the namespace urn:h17-org:v3 does not have a prefix, you have to create a reference to it with a prefix in your stylesheet tag, which I  created as ns1. So, any time you want to reference ClinicalDocument or any of it's child or grandchild nodes you have to use the ns1 prefix. Also, you can't put ns1 in exclude-result-prefixes and exclude it.

Comment: You are a champion @bluewood66. thanks it works fine